# Javascript push list on object empty array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a list of tags from an object

Here is the full code and data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

obj = 

{
    "category":[
    {

    "id":"8098",
        "tags":{
            "411":"something",
            "414":"something else"
        }
    }

]

};


var tagList = [];

for (var index in obj) {

  for (var indexSub in obj[index].tags) {

       blah = (obj[index].tags[indexSub]);
       tagList.push(blah);
   }
}

console.log(tagList);



});
```

Here's a link to [jsFiddle](http://httphttps://jsfiddle.net/myfiddles2016/f6ogkvzr/12/)

The problem is that taglist is returning an empty array.

How can I fix this?

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: "id" is not in the same level as "category" its actually inside the array that "category" refers to, so your iteration never finds the "id" key

Comment: I've added a link to jsfiddle

Comment: Are all of your objects going to have the same structure as this one? If so, you can just loop through obj.category.id.tags, otherwise we'll have to fix the loops you have now. I'll post an answer based on your reply to this.

Comment: Yes, I just want to get the list of tag names and put them into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours

```
    for (var index in obj) {

        for (var indexSub in obj[index].tags) {

            blah = (obj[index].tags[indexSub]);
            tagList.push(blah);
        }
    }
```

New to get the `tags` that are into the `category`

```
for (var index in obj) {
  for (var indexSub in obj[index]) {
     blah = (obj[index][indexSub].tags);
     tagList.push(blah);
  }
}
```

See the diference in the way to access the properties

```js
 
        obj =
            {
                "category": [
                    {
                        "id": "8098",
                        "tags": {
                            "411": "something",
                            "414": "something else"
                        }
                    }

                ]

            };


        var tagList = [];

        for (var index in obj) {

            for (var indexSub in obj[index]) {
                tagList = (obj[index][indexSub].tags);
               // tagList.push(blah);
            }
        }

        console.log(tagList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the category, and then get the keys and values of tags, somethig like this..

```js
var obj = 
{
    "category":[
    {

    "id":"8098",
        "tags":{
            "411":"something",
            "414":"something else"
        }
    }

]};

var tagList = [];

obj.category.forEach( o =>{
  for (property in o.tags){
   tagList.push(property + ':'+ o.tags[property]);  
  };
});

console.log(tagList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm9r9wjt/2/)

```
obj = 
{
   "category":[
          {
             "id":"8098",
             "tags":{
                 "411":"something",
                 "414":"something else"
             }
          }

   ]
};
var tagList = [];
for (key in obj) {
    for(subKey in obj[key]){
            var myTags=obj[key][subKey].tags;
            for(tag in myTags){
                 tagList.push(tag);
            }
    }

}
console.log(tagList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for iterating and getting all tags.

```js
var obj = { "category": [{ "id": "8098", "tags": { "411": "something", "414": "something else" } }] },
    tagList = obj.category.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(Object.keys(a.tags).map(function (t) { return a.tags[t]; }));
    }, []);

console.log(tagList);
```